# How to translate a known binary data into a object in Python?

Tags: python, io, binary, pickle

For example, I already know a binary data:

```
"b'\x80\x03}q\x00(X\x03\x00\x00\x00ageq\x01K\x14X\x05\x00\x00\x00scoreq\x02KXX\x04\x00\x00\x00nameq\x03X\x03\x00\x00\x00Bobq\x04u.'"
```

It is a dict object.

How can I translate it into a dict object? I can only find the way to read files into a object, but I can't find the way to translate the existing data into object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert the binary data to a python object using the [pickle module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html):

```
>>> bs = b'\x80\x03}q\x00(X\x03\x00\x00\x00ageq\x01K\x14X\x05\x00\x00\x00scoreq\x02KXX\x04\x00\x00\x00nameq\x03X\x03\x00\x00\x00Bobq\x04u.'
>>> import pickle
>>> loaded = pickle.loads(bs)
>>> loaded
{'score': 88, 'age': 20, 'name': 'Bob'}
```

Note that this will only work on objects that were serialized using the tools in the pickle module - `pickle.dump` or `pickle.dumps`.  The pickle module can't deserialise arbitrary binary data.

Also, you should only unpickle objects from a trusted source, as unpickling an object could cause code execution.